# Is 3DES = DES do 3 times?

Tags: java, android, des, 3des

I have done a DES Util class according to [mkyong's JCE Encryption – Data Encryption Standard (DES) Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jce-encryption-data-encryption-standard-des-tutorial/)

Here's my class:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import tw.com.januarytc.android.singularsdk.lib.JsLib;
import android.util.Log;

public class DESUtil
{
  private KeyGenerator keyGen=null;
  private SecretKey sKey=null;
  private Cipher desCip=null;

  /**
   * Init. DES utility class
   * @return boolean
   */
  public boolean init()
  {
    boolean b=false;

    try
    {
      keyGen=KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
      sKey=keyGen.generateKey();
      desCip=Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
      b=true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      Log.d(JsLib.TAG, "Init DESUtil failed: "+e.toString());
      e.printStackTrace();
      b=false;
    }
    return b;
  }

  /**
   * Encrypt string with DES
   * @param str - Original string
   * @return java.lang.String DES encrypted string
   * @throws IllegalStateException
   */
  public String encryptString(String str) throws IllegalStateException
  {
    if(keyGen==null || sKey==null || desCip==null){throw new IllegalStateException("DESUtil class has not been initialized.");}
    String ret="";
    try
    {
      desCip.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKey);
      ret=new String(desCip.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      ret="";
    }
    return ret;
  }

  /**
   * Decrypt string which encrypted by DES
   * @param str - DES encrypted string
   * @return java.lang.String Original string
   * @throws IllegalStateException
   */
  public String decryptString(String strDes) throws IllegalStateException
  {
    if(keyGen==null || sKey==null || desCip==null){throw new IllegalStateException("DESUtil class has not been initialized.");}
    String ret="";
    try
    {
      desCip.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sKey);
      ret=new String(desCip.doFinal(strDes.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      ret="";
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

And as WiKi said:

In cryptography, Triple DES is the common name for the Triple Data Encryption Algorithm (TDEA or Triple DEA) block cipher, which **applies the Data Encryption Standard (DES) cipher algorithm three times to each data block**.

I'm just wondering what if I encrypt a string with DES for 3 times...Will it equals 3DES ?

Thanks for suggestions, and sorry for my poor english~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DES uses a short 56 bit key, which was vulnerable to brute force attacks. 3DES uses 168 bit keys (56x3), and performs the encryption like so:

1. Encrypt clear text using the 1st 56 bits of the key, produce output1
2. **Decrypt** output1 using the 2nd 56 bits of the key, produce output2
3. Encrypt output2 using the 3rd 56 bits of they, produce encrypted text.

Her's a reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES

Comment: 3DES was actually designed this way to be backward compatible with single DES. Data encrypted with a 3DES key where all three 56 bit parts are the same, will give the same as data encrypted with a single DES key with the 56 bit. This way all single DES encrypted data would be accessible with a 3DES implementation as well.

Answer (score 3):

`3DES` does perform `DES` 3 times, but with three different keys. This algorithm was designed to get around DES's inherent lack of security associated with the original key size.